# Android File.createTemFile() not giving proper name to file

Tags: android, android-activity, file-io

I am trying to use the below code to create a temp file to pass to the camera

```
        File storageDir = new 
File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICT
    URES).getAbsolutePath());
        File imageFile = File.createTempFile("pic_" + 
    System.currentTimeMillis(), ".jpg", storageDir);
```

This is creating a file with name -

> /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/pic_1435562082710-1045324751.jpg

My query - 
 where is this figure (-1045324751) coming from?

I have tried parsing the `System.currentTimeMillis()` result into int, String but its coming same with every case

Answer (score 0):

That part is coming from Android itself. Creating a temp file ensures you to get a unique filename, so it adds a part to the filename, it is outside of your control.